# CMake: how to get compiler "system" flags?

Tags: c++, cmake

I'm trying to print using `message` all the compiler flags passed to my targets (they are the same for all targets). (Why? I need to pass them to cldoc to generate documentation using clang...).

Under MacOs I realize when doing `make VERBOSE=1` that the following flags are passed to clang:

`-isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.9.sdk -mmacosx-version-min=10.9`

What is the CMake variable that gives me these in a portable way?

Note: AFAIK they are not in: `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS`, `CMAKE_CXX_COMPILE_FLAGS`, `CMAKE_CXX_LINK_FLAGS`, `CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS`, `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE/DEBUG`, `CMAKE_C_FLAGS`, `CMAKE_C_COMPILE_FLAGS`, `CMAKE_C_LINK_FLAGS`.

Comment: Isn't there a property `COMPILE_FLAGS` for each target?

Comment: Yes but when I pass the flags to cldoc there are actually no targets yet. Still clang needs the compilation flags to understand the code.

Answer (score 1):

In my project I just use additional definition in my head CMakeList.txt with the "-v" command:     `add_definitions(-v)`

Is similar to add `VERBOSE=1` to the make command.

Comment: Yes, that is what I ended up doing with a dummy file and then manually stripping out the compiler to get just the system flags.

Comment: You can also use `set(CMAKE_VERBOSE_MAKEFILE ON)` on your top CMakeLists.txt